# How to extends a class of a module?

Tags: node.js

I am using modern Javascript (EC6+) code with `node --experimental-modules`.

```
import bigInt from 'big-integer';  // npm i big-integer

console.log(bigInt(333).toString(2)) // fine

class bigIntB4 extends bigInt {
    constructor(...args) {
       super(...args);
    }
    test() {
       console.log("Hello!")
    }
}

let c = new bigIntB4(333)  //fine
console.log(c.toString(2)) // fine
c.test()   // BUG!
```

Error: "TypeError: c.test is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bigInt` is not a constructor function.](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/blob/4a5b73a2d6a9a7a8aa78e4a095cc55e4d498f691/BigInteger.js#L12-L16) It's a normal function that returns an object. As such you cannot really extend it.

Here is a simplified example of the issue:

```js
function Foo() {
  return {foo: 42};
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

console.log(new Bar instanceof Bar);
console.log(new Bar);
```

The value returned by `new Bar` is the value returned by `Foo`, which does not extend `Bar.prototype`.

---

If you need only to add a new method, [at least](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/issues/170#issuecomment-462634155), you can modify the prototype:

```
bigInt.prototype.test = function () {
  console.log("Hello!");
};
```

Comment: Thanks Felix!  Yes, now I see the  [bigInt module source code](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/blob/master/BigInteger.js), it is as expressed in the  (ugly) "old  style"  for modules... Well, as you demonstred it is impossible without rewrite it.  Didactic answer.